# Definite article before person's function and name

Tags: grammar, definite-articles, names

Which of the following is preferred in scientific writing?

> The resulting function is is called the *Bragg curve*, after British physicist William Henry Bragg.

or

> The resulting function is is called the *Bragg curve*, after **the** British physicist William Henry Bragg.

Google has much more hits for the second version, but the first one sounds better to me (as a non-native english speaker).

Comment: Either is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine. *British physicist W.H.B* uses a restrictive appositive, and in such cases the definite article is often dropped.

It is dropped because it usually doesn't add much, if anything. Consider:

- *The `foo` parameter and the `bar` parameter of the function `toto` take integer values.*
- *The `foo` and `bar` parameters of the function `toto` take integer values.*
- *Parameters `foo` and `bar` of function `toto` take integer values.*
- *The `foo` table has the columns `toto` and `titi`.*
- *Table `foo` has columns `toto` and `titi`.*

See also [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/138951/4544), which is essentially a duplicate of this one (but is on sister site ELL).